# improved regularization for $\lambda$-convex gradient flows

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, convex-analysis, parabolic-pde, optimal-transportation

It is well-known that gradient-flows of convex functionals are "parabolic" in some vague sense, and accordingly solutions tend to regularize instataneously. In the abstract context of gradient flows in metric spaces one has

> **Theorem** Let $(X,d)$ be a "nice" metric space, and $\Phi:X\to\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ a convex function. If $t\mapsto u_t$ is a solution to the gradient-flow
>    $$
>  "\dot u_t=-\nabla\Phi(u_t)"
>  $$
>    then for any $w\in X$ there holds
>    $$
>  |\partial\Phi|^2(u_t) \leq \frac{1}{t^2} d^2(u_0,w)+|\partial\Phi|^2(w).
>  $$
>    In particular if $\Phi$ attains a minimum at a point $w$ (with $|\partial\Phi|(w)=0$) then this quantifies an instantaneous regularization: The slope decreases at $t=0$ at least as
>   \begin{equation}
> \label{eq:regularization}
> |\partial\Phi|^2(u_t) \leq \frac{C}{t^2}
> \tag{R1}
> \end{equation}
>   wih $C=d^2(u_0,w)$ depending only on the initial datum.
>   Moreover if $\Phi$ has modulus of convexity $\lambda>0$ then
>   \begin{equation}
> \label{eq:regularization2}
> |\partial\Phi|^2(u_t) \leq  e^{-2\lambda t} |\partial\Phi|^2(u_0)
> \tag{R2}
> \end{equation}

Here $|\partial\Phi|(v)$ denotes the metric slope at a point $v\in X$, and the ODE $"\dot u_t=-\nabla\Phi(u_t)"$ should be understood in the abstract metric sense, for example in the sense of Energy-Dissipation-Inequality - see [AGS]. Please allow me to remain sloppy here and dispense from the technical details/assumptions in order to avoid burdening the exposition (see e.g. [AGS, Theorem 11.2.1] for a rigorous statement in a precise context). This is easy to prove for example in the framework of Hilbert spaces.

---

### Question:

> The instantaneous regularization \eqref{eq:regularization} holds if
>   the driving functional is merely convex, i-e has a modulus of
>   convexity $0$. Can we strengthen this estimate under the stronger hypothesis that $\Phi$
>   has a modulus of convexity $\lambda>0$? Typically one would expect a
>   better rate
>   $$
> |\partial\Phi|^2(u_t)\leq \frac{C}{t}\qquad ???
> $$
>   for some $C>0$ possibly depending on $u_0,\lambda$. Of course
>   \eqref{eq:regularization2} is already much stronger (and optimal), but it requires the initial regularity $|\partial \Phi|(u_0)<\infty$ to make sense. What if $u_0\not\in D(\partial\Phi)$?

Actually any improvement of the form $|\partial\Phi|^2(u_t)\leq \frac{C}{t^{2-\epsilon}}$ with $\epsilon>0$ would suffice for my purpose.

For a non-trivial example of this improved regularity, take the (quadratic) Wasserstein space $(\mathcal P(\mathbb T^d),\mathcal W_2)$ on the flat torus, and take as a driving functional the entropy $\Phi(u)=H(u)=\int_{\mathbb T^d} u\log u\,dx$ (with the convention that $H(u)+\infty$ whenever $u$ is not absolutely continuous w.r.t the Lebesgue measure $dx$). The the gradient flow is the linear heat equation $\partial_t u=\Delta u$, and the (squared) slope is nothing but the Fisher information $|\partial H|^2(u)= F(u)=\int_{\mathbb T^d} \frac{|\nabla u|^2}{u}=\int_{\mathbb T^d}|\nabla\log u|^2 u$. From \eqref{eq:regularization} we already know that $F(u_t)\leq \frac{C}{t^2}$. However from the Li-Yau inequality [2] (see [my previous post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/311257/universal-decay-rate-of-the-fisher-information-along-the-heat-flow)) it is know that the Fisher information decays at the BETTER universal rate $F(u_t)\leq \frac{C}{t}$ and in this case \eqref{eq:regularization} is clearly suboptimal.

I would be happy with an aswer even in Hilbert spaces (the statement is probably vacuous in finite dimension, though)

---

[AGS] Ambrosio, L., Gigli, N., & Savaré, G. (2008). Gradient flows: in metric spaces and in the space of probability measures. Springer Science & Business Media.

[LY] Li, P., Yau, S.T.: On the parabolic kernel of the Schrödinger operator. Acta Mathematica
156(1), 153–201 (1986)